# Using instances in Javascript - @class, @param, @property, @augments

Tags: javascript, instance

I got a javascript file. There are 3 classes and I need to create these classes instances and use the methods they contain. Problem is, these 3 classes are not like `class Example {...}`. Instead they look like this:

```
* @class
* @param {Array|Object} param1 - [REQUIRED]
* @param {Array|String} param2 - [OPTIONAL]
* @property {String} prop1
* @property {String} prop2
* @property {Array} prop3
* @property {Class2} prop4

function Class1(param1, param2) {
    ...
}

@augments Class1
@param {String} param5
@return {String}

Class1.prototype.someName = function (param5) {
    ...
}
```

And it goes like this. My questions are:

1) What does `@class` or `property` etc. mean?

2) What is difference between `func Class1` and `Class1.prototype.someName` ?

3) How can I create `instance` from these 3 classes and use the methods from another js file. Because I need to create everything from this javascript file. They contain some HTML with CSS classes like:

```
function Class1(param1, param2) {
    this.openTag;
    this.closeTag;
    this.htmlTags;

    this.openTag = '<div id="' + this.elementId + '">';
    this.closeTag = '</div>';

    this.htmlTags = {
        sectionTitle: {
            openTag: '<h2 class="class1">',
            closeTag: '</h2>'
        },
        group: {
            openTag: '<div class="class2">',
            closeTag: '</div>'
        },
        table: {
            openTag: '<table class="class3">',
            closeTag: '</table>'
        }
    }
   ...
}
```

How can I create an instance of these classes and call them from another javascript file? When I try to do ES6 imports/exports, it gives me this error:

`Access to script at 'file:///Users/user/Desktop/project/someName.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

&

`app.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

It doesn't allow me to call functions from another js file.

I would appreciate if you explain everything step by step :)

Comment: Seems like this is JSDoc. You've omitted some characters - those `@` directives are supposed to be inside a block comment.

Comment: 1) is JSDoc. Nothing more than comments that support generation of api docs. 2) The "classes" are new in JavaScript, before we had these functions. You'll find a lot of articles in the web 3) `new Class1()`, this article could help: https://medium.com/@parsyval/javascript-prototype-vs-class-a7015d5473b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***What does `@class` mean?***

This is something called JSDoc. It's basically the equivalent of the summary xml comments for c#. At a high level, it's just a *better* way to document your methods, classes, variables, functions, etc... rather than just doing `//...` everywhere. You can learn more about JSDoc [here](https://devdocs.io/jsdoc/howto-es2015-classes). Other languages have similar things. I am most familiar with c# and JS though.

The cool thing about JSDoc is that if you have an IDE that supports it, you can basically just hover over something and assuming you've got proper JSDoc on whatever module you're using, you'll get the documentation right then and there. You don't have to hop over to the source to see if the author left any comments for you. They'll just pop up inline. WebStorm does a good job with this.

***What is the difference between `func Class1` and `Class1.prototype.someName`***

This (IMO) is the old school way of writting classes in JavaScript. With ES6+, you can just use the keyword `class` instead of `function` and having to use prototypes.

Essentially,

`function Class1 (...) {...}`

is the older way of doing

`class Class1 { ... }`

With that being said ,

`Class1.prototype.someName = function (...) { ... }`

is the old school way of doing

```
class Class1 () {
    constructor(...) {...}
    someName(...) { ... }

}
```

For your 3rd question, I am unclear what you're asking.

Example of using modern day classes vs the 'older' way:

```js
// Older way of creating a Person class
function Person(first, last) {
  this.first = first;
  this.last = last;
}

Person.prototype = {
  getFullName: function () {
    return this.first + ' ' + this.last;
  }
}

var oldPerson = new Person('John', 'Doe');
console.log(oldPerson.getFullName());

// Modern way of creating a class

class Person1 {
  constructor(first, last) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
  }
  getFullName() {
    return `${this.first} ${this.last}`;
  }
}

const newPerson = new Person1('Jane', 'Doe');
console.log(newPerson.getFullName());
```

Comment: 3rd question: I need to use this js file from another using instance. Some methods  in this javascript file creates HTML elements. I need to create my DOM with using this js file.

Comment: JavaScript classes and DOM/HTML are two separate things. They can interact with each other, of course, but are not exclusively related. I need a lot more information before I can make any sense of that.

Comment: So how can I call these functions from another file?

Comment: Look into ES6 imports/exports. I don't know what your setup is so it's impossible to tell you how to do that without knowing.

Comment: I editted my question about ES6 imports/exports. Could you take look?

Comment: If you mark this answer as an accepted answer (as it addresses your question) and open up a new question specific to how import / export works, I'd be happy to take a look and provide an answer